# Getting Text Colour with PDFBox

Tags: java, pdfbox

I have just started working with PDFBox, extracting text and so on. One thing I am interested in is the colour of the text itself that I am extracting. However I cannot seem to find any way of getting that information.

Is it possible at all to use PDFBox to get the colour information of a document and if so, how would I go about doing so?

Many thanks.

Answer (score 4):

All color informations should be stored in the class `PDGraphicsState` and the used color (stroking/nonstroking etc.) depends on the used text rendering mode *(via pdfbox mailing list)*.

Here is a small sample I tried:

After creating a pdf with just one line ("Sample" written in `RGB=[146,208,80]`), the following program will output:

> DeviceRGB
>   146.115
>   208.08
>   80.07

Here's the code:

```
PDDocument doc = null;
try {
    doc = PDDocument.load("C:/Path/To/Pdf/Sample.pdf");
    PDFStreamEngine engine = new PDFStreamEngine(ResourceLoader.loadProperties("org/apache/pdfbox/resources/PageDrawer.properties"));
    PDPage page = (PDPage)doc.getDocumentCatalog().getAllPages().get(0);
    engine.processStream(page, page.findResources(), page.getContents().getStream());
    PDGraphicsState graphicState = engine.getGraphicsState();
    System.out.println(graphicState.getStrokingColor().getColorSpace().getName());
    float colorSpaceValues[] = graphicState.getStrokingColor().getColorSpaceValue();
    for (float c : colorSpaceValues) {
        System.out.println(c * 255);
    }
}
finally {
    if (doc != null) {
        doc.close();
    }
```

Take a look at `PageDrawer.properties` to see how PDF operators are mapped to Java classes.

As I understand it, as `PDFStreamEngine` processes a page stream, it sets various variable states depending on what operators it is processing at the moment. So when it hits green text, it will change the PDGraphicsState because it will encounter appropriate operators. So for `CS` it calls `org.apache.pdfbox.util.operator.SetStrokingColorSpace` as defined by mapping `CS=org.apache.pdfbox.util.operator.SetStrokingColorSpace` in the `.properties` file. `RG` is mapped to `org.apache.pdfbox.util.operator.SetStrokingRGBColor` and so on.

In this case, the `PDGraphicsState` hasn't changed because the document has just text and the text it has is in just one style. For something more advanced, you would need to extend `PDFStreamEngine` (just like `PageDrawer`, `PDFTextStripper` and other classes do) to do something when color changes. You could also write your own mappings in your own `.properties` file.

Comment: If I am not mistaken, he asked for the textcolor and not for the color of the stroking

Comment: @Erik: Please see PDF reference (partners.adobe.com/public/developer/en/pdf/PDFReference.pdf) to learn how text is colored in PDF documents.

Comment: @Erik No problem. I would be very happy if someone could give an authoritative answer on this one, and perhaps make the whole process less cumbersome.

Comment: I don't believe ResourceLoader is still up to date; it is not available in PdfBox 2.0.23.