# Extracting font-color for text in a pdf in Java using PDFBox

Tags: java, pdfbox

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Getting Text Colour with PDFBox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5861471/getting-text-colour-with-pdfbox)

I have just started working with PDFBox, extracting text and so on. One thing I am interested in is the colour of the text. However there seems to be no way of getting that information.

Is it possible at all to use PDFBox to get the colour information of a document and if so, how would I go about doing so?

Comment: Please see the answer to a very similar question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5861471/getting-text-colour-with-pdfbox