# Color text extraction PDFBOX

Tags: java, fonts, colors, extract, pdfbox

I try this code

```
PDDocument doc = null;

    try 
    {
        doc = PDDocument.load("C:/Users/bcalvo/Desktop/leon/20130710.pdf");
        //doc = PDDocument.load("C:/Users/bcalvo/Desktop/color.pdf");
        PDFStreamEngine engine = new PDFStreamEngine(ResourceLoader.loadProperties("org/apache/pdfbox/resources/PageDrawer.properties"));
        PDPage page = (PDPage)doc.getDocumentCatalog().getAllPages().get(0);
        engine.processStream(page, page.findResources(), page.getContents().getStream());
        PDGraphicsState graphicState = engine.getGraphicsState();

        System.out.println("color: " + graphicState.getStrokingColor().getColorSpace().getName());

        //System.out.println("color: " + graphicState.getStrokingColor().getJavaColor() );

        float colorSpaceValues[] = graphicState.getStrokingColor().getColorSpaceValue();

        for (float c : colorSpaceValues) 
            System.out.println(c * 255);
    }
    finally 
    {
        if (doc != null) 
            doc.close();
    }       
}
```

And when I execute it show me the next error:

jul 10, 2013 1:23:31 PM org.apache.pdfbox.util.PDFStreamEngine processOperator WARNING: java.lang.ClassCastException: org.apache.pdfbox.util.PDFStreamEngine cannot be cast to org.apache.pdfbox.pdfviewer.PageDrawer java.lang.ClassCastException: org.apache.pdfbox.util.PDFStreamEngine cannot be cast to org.apache.pdfbox.pdfviewer.PageDrawer at org.apache.pdfbox.util.operator.pagedrawer.CurveTo.process(CurveTo.java:45) at org.apache.pdfbox.util.PDFStreamEngine.processOperator(PDFStreamEngine.java:554) at org.apache.pdfbox.util.PDFStreamEngine.processSubStream(PDFStreamEngine.java:268) at org.apache.pdfbox.util.PDFStreamEngine.processSubStream(PDFStreamEngine.java:235) at org.apache.pdfbox.util.PDFStreamEngine.processStream(PDFStreamEngine.java:215) at com.prueba.ExtractColorFonts.main(ExtractColorFonts.java:26)

The line which it refers the error is this:

engine.processStream(page, page.findResources(), page.getContents().getStream());

Somebody knows how to repair this error?

Comment: The problem is you're loading the PageDrawer properties, but the context that you're using it within is the basic PDFStreamEngine. That code looks pretty familiar to this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/14064675/862594

Comment: i used serveral examples that i find on the web. But never works on myy proyect. i need somebody explains me how can i do