# pdfbox extract color font on a pdf error

Tags: pdf, text, fonts, colors, pdfbox

hi everybody sorry for my english level but i'm not english/american.

my question is the next: i try to use the example code that where posted in this site ([How to get font color using pdfbox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10844271/how-to-get-font-color-using-pdfbox/14064675#14064675)) in the example, the author says that the code was tried but when i tried it shows me this error:

jul 17, 2013 1:05:28 PM org.apache.pdfbox.util.PDFStreamEngine processOperator
INFO: unsupported/disabled operation: BDC
jul 17, 2013 1:05:29 PM org.apache.pdfbox.util.PDFStreamEngine processOperator
INFO: unsupported/disabled operation: EMC
DeviceGray
org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.graphics.color.PDColorState@481958
0.0

the pdf that i was extracting contents 3 letters (RGB) which is painted :

R: painted in red color
G: painted in green color
B: painted in black color

somebody can explain me because is this error o tell me how can i do to extract color text from a pdf?

thanks for all for the futures comments

Answer (score 0):

Those log outputs are of level INFO only, not error:

```
jul 17, 2013 1:05:28 PM org.apache.pdfbox.util.PDFStreamEngine processOperator INFO: unsupported/disabled operation: BDC
jul 17, 2013 1:05:29 PM org.apache.pdfbox.util.PDFStreamEngine processOperator INFO: unsupported/disabled operation: EMC
```

All they say is that certain operators (BDC, EMC) were encountered in the page content for which no processor was registered. But as those operators are of interest for analyzing marked content only, those operators can be ignored for your task.

Thereafter you have output from the code you referred to:

```
DeviceGray
org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.graphics.color.PDColorState@481958
0.0
```

At least the first and the last line match that code: A color in DeviceGray gray with gray value 0 was encountered, most likely your black **B**. (Could it be you have added an additional output in-between, e.g. of `graphicState.getStrokingColor()`?)

Thus, no error, all working fine.

Comment: thnks for your answer. No i don't added an additional output, just tried the code because i need to extract the text on a pdf that have 3 kinds of color text and i need to extract each text. I am not enough expercience using PDFBOX then i tried to use the examples, but unlike is that for me no shows me the color RGB of the extracted text. simply shows me DeviceGray 0.0 and the text is wrotten in 3 colors (red, blue and green). it could be that the import PageDrawer properties aren't included?

Comment: The code shows the color after the whole stream has been processed. Usually in a stream the current state is stored, something is done, and then the previous state is restored. That might explain that the current color after everything has been done is black. I think you want to derive from `PDFStreamEngine` similar to `PDFTextStripper` but with a `processTextPosition` that also takes the current colors into account.

Comment: using PDFStreamEngine with proceesTextPosition i can to extract the text by color of each char?

Comment: When you are in `proceesTextPosition,` you can query the graphic state at the moment current `TextPosition` text is drawn.