# Unable to resolve import org.apache.fontbox.util.ResourceLoader in pdfbox 2.0.5

Tags: java, build.gradle, pdfbox

I am trying to get the text color from the pdf document. I am loading PageDrawer.properties using ResourceLoader in constructor of the class as given below. I have defined pdfbox version to 1.5.0 in build.gradle but it is downloading pdfbox version 2.0.5

```js
public PdfTest() throws IOException {
        super(ResourceLoader.loadProperties(
                "org/apache/pdfbox/resources/PageDrawer.properties", new Properties()));
        super.setSortByPosition(true);
    }
```

By above code I am not able to load property "import org.apache.fontbox.util.ResourceLoader". 
Does anyone have any idea why pdfbox 2.0.5 is donloaded instead of 1.5.0? Also how to resolve ResourceLoader issue?

build.gradle

```js
group 'abc'
version '1.0-SNAPSHOT'

apply plugin: 'groovy'
apply plugin: 'java'

sourceCompatibility = 1.5

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    compile 'org.codehaus.groovy:groovy-all:2.3.11'
    testCompile group: 'junit', name: 'junit', version: '4.11'
    compile group: 'org.apache.pdfbox', name: 'pdfbox', version: '1.8.3'
}
```

I tried it with IntelliJ it was downloading 1.8.3, but on Android Studio(2.3.2) it was downloading 2.0.5.

Comment: Should't you include your build.gradle file here? Btw PDFBox 1.5.0 is from 2011. The last PDFBox version that uses org/apache/pdfbox/resources/PageDrawer.properties is 1.8.13.

Comment: If i want to use 2.0.5 and load PageDrawer.properties then how do I load the property? I referred https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10844271/how-to-get-font-color-using-pdfbox. Why version pdfbox 2.0.5 is downloaded even when I mentioned version 1.5.0 or 1.8.3?

Comment: "If i want to use 2.0.5" - then see the last answer in the link in your comment. "Why version pdfbox 2.0.5 is downloaded" - that's why I asked you to include your build.gradle file. (You can edit your question).

Comment: 1) Please check the import for ResourceLoader, this should be `import org.apache.pdfbox.util.ResourceLoader;` and not anything with fontbox. 2) try adding fontbox to your build.gradle file with the same version. 3) The latest 1.8 version is 1.8.13, not 1.8.3.